# How do I allow the user to create their own option

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

So I've got a couple lines of code that give the user the option to pick a start and endpoint, once picked they click the link and are redirected to a google maps page that already has the directions set out for them. I'm trying to add a function that enables the user to save their own options as locations. Without context this makes little sense so heres my code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function updateNavigationLink() {
        var link = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
            encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("start").value)      +
            "&daddr=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("end").value);
        document.getElementById("navigationLink").href = link; 
    }
</script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ISHGUIDE</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div class=naviselection>
    Start:
    <input type='text' list='startinput' id="start" onchange="updateNavigationLink()" />
    <datalist id="startinput" >  
    <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
    <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
</datalist>   

    End:
    <input type="text" id="end" list="endinput" onchange="updateNavigationLink()"/>
        <datalist id="endinput" >
        <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
        <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
    </datalist>
</div>

<div class=Finallink>
    <a id="navigationLink">NAVILINK</a>         
</div>
```

I would like to create a function in which the user is provided the ability to save locations as different options for example:

Location: PUT LOCATION HERE
Name: PUT NAME HERE

They could put their house address in the location bar and "home" in the option bar. Then, this line of code would be added to my script:

```
<option value="house address">HOME</option>
```

How would I go about creating this function and ensuring it works as I would like it to.

Thank you for your help it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to write this function *at all*?

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately it hasn't worked as planned.

Comment: probably because `datalist` is only properly supported in niche browsers

Comment: I can see how that could disable the code from functioning.